# Difficulty in creating new variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I need like to create some new variables of years (2015, 2016, ---, 2022) based on start date and end date. If someone's year of start date is 2017 and year of end date is 2020 then for that person value in 2017, 2018, 2019, and 2020 columns will be 'Yes'

I used the following code and got the attached table.

```
select *
  ,case when startdate >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' and enddate <= '2015-12-31 00:00:00.000' then 'yes' end as '2015'
  ,case when startdate >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000' and enddate <= '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' then 'yes' end as '2016' 
  ,case when startdate >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000' and enddate <= '2017-12-31 00:00:00.000' then 'yes' end as '2017' 
  ,case when startdate >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' and enddate <= '2018-12-31 00:00:00.000' then 'yes' end as '2018' 
  ,case when startdate >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000' and enddate <= '2019-12-31 00:00:00.000' then 'yes' end as '2019' 
  ,case when startdate >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000' and enddate <= '2020-12-31 00:00:00.000' then 'yes' end as '2020' 
  ,case when startdate >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000' and enddate <= '2021-12-31 00:00:00.000' then 'yes' end as '2021' 
  ,case when startdate >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00.000' and enddate <= '2022-12-31 00:00:00.000' then 'yes' end as '2022' 
 from #have
 order by ID
```

[Using the code mentioned above, I got the attached table. Someone's start date is in 2018 and end date is in 2020. They are not showing as 'Yes' in those years.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYrMK.png)

Comment: your cases only cover cases where start and end dates are in the same year - there is nothing that will give you "yes" when start date is in one year and end date is in another year.

Comment: Which database is this?

Comment: SQL server management studio

Comment: Yes, my cases only cover cases where start and end dates are in the same year - there is nothing that will give me "yes" when start date is in one year and end date is in another year. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Telling us SQL Server Management Studio is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the name you see on the dashboard radio. Fine for most, but alarming from your mechanic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution. See below

```
select *
  ,case when  2015 >= year(startdate) and 2015 <= year(enddate) then 'yes' end as '2015'
  ,case when  2016 >= year(startdate) and 2016 <= year(enddate) then 'yes' end as '2016'
  ,case when  2017 >= year(startdate) and 2017 <= year(enddate) then 'yes' end as '2017'
  ,case when  2018 >= year(startdate) and 2018 <= year(enddate) then 'yes' end as '2018'
  ,case when  2019 >= year(startdate) and 2019 <= year(enddate) then 'yes' end as '2019'
  ,case when  2020 >= year(startdate) and 2020 <= year(enddate) then 'yes' end as '2020'
  ,case when  2021 >= year(startdate) and 2021 <= year(enddate) then 'yes' end as '2021'
  ,case when  2022 >= year(startdate) and 2022 <= year(enddate) then 'yes' end as '2022'
from #Have
order by PID
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
   ,case when startdate < '20160101' and enddate > '20150101' then 'yes' end as "2015"
   ,case when startdate < '20170101' and enddate > '20160101' then 'yes' end as "2016"
   ,case when startdate < '20180101' and enddate > '20170101' then 'yes' end as "2017"
   ,case when startdate < '20190101' and enddate > '20180101' then 'yes' end as "2018"
   ,case when startdate < '20200101' and enddate > '20190101' then 'yes' end as "2019"
   ,case when startdate < '20210101' and enddate > '20200101' then 'yes' end as "2020"
   ,case when startdate < '20220101' and enddate > '20210101' then 'yes' end as "2021"
   ,case when startdate < '20230101' and enddate > '20220101' then 'yes' end as "2022"
 from #have
 order by ID
```

There's probably also a way to do this using a `CROSS APPLY` to a table-value constructor `VALUES()` clause, but I'm not even sure what database you're using so I won't try guess at the right syntax just yet.